# Create Trigger in PHPMyAdmin to Repair Table on Crash

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, phpbb

I'm running PHPBB (most up-to-date non-beta version) and in the last 3 months, the error appears during a search every few days:

'phpbb_search_wordmatch' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

To fix it, I then just run a repair on the table. I am still working on a way to figure out why this keeps crashing. The host was not helpful and it could be that the table is too large for the server (700 mb or so)

My Question: Could I create a trigger in PHPMyAdmin in the meantime to automatically repair the table whenever this error happens? You see it on the table in PMA when you go to access it, so there must be some entry that I can use to create the trigger.

Unfortunately this issue is difficult to fix for me being on a shared server, and all resources online say to contact the host, so as long as I can at least get it to fix itself when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off setting up a scheduled task. I'm not aware of how you could create a trigger that detects when the table needs repair; I don't believe there are hooks for the logic to detect that situation and cause a procedure to run.

From the database, there's an Events tab where you can enable the MySQL event scheduler and create an event which would run, say, once per week and run the SQL statement to repair the table. It's still not ideal, but I think it's better than using a trigger in this case.

Comment: Thank you; sorry for not responding to this. I assumed I would have received a notification but I guess my spam folder ate it up.

I have added an event, I think. So we will see if it runs. I had to do it every day because if I let it go a week, people would explode on me. 

The only thing is now that it is in there it says Event Scheduler Status: OFF, and it says I do not have Super Permissions to toggle it on a global level. Not sure if I need it to be global, so I am hoping this is okay.